# installing RealmSwift pod also installs Realm (ObjC)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

While installing the Realm Cocoapod with `pod RealmSwift` I get this message

```
Installing Realm (0.95.3)
Installing RealmSwift (0.95.3)
```

Does this mean that both wrappers are installed, Objective-C *and* Swift? So I could import `"Realm.h"` in Objective-C classes and `RealmSwift` in Swift? To me it looks like this works.

EDIT: I do want to use Realm with a mixed project using Objective-C and Swift in the projects classes. The question is, if I only need to install the Pod `RealmSwift`

Comment: I don't know how exactly RealmSwift is configured or works but it is possible that it is only a swift binding on top of the Realm objC code, then it would be normal to have a dependency on the ObjC version, and you would get both when you request the swift one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RealmSwift is a wrapper around existing code in Objective-C++. As Swift is still a "work in progress" and Realm has a very large codebase, it is more convenient to start wrapping the older code around and give the Swift features out to the developers without having to redo everything from scratch.

I do not know what is the plan for future, but the contributors to Realm taught this concept in a [workshop](http://www.meetup.com/Paris-Tech-Talks/events/219801628/):

> In this workshop, you'll create a Swift wrapper framework around a small existing Objective-C library.

To answer your question - *no*. The Swift wrapper is there to support Swift features, but really only calls the older functions with some other work around it to give it the *Swifty* feeling.

Comment: This also needed because Realm's Core is written in C++ and there is no other way to interface C++ from Swift than going over Objective-C at the moment.